# VBA behaves differently after close and re-open

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 on a PC running Windows Vista.

The Access database with VBA code in many modules works as expected.  However, one module acts differently after I have exited the database and re-entered.  As soon as I re-enter, I can select View Code and Save without changing any code and the program goes back to working the way I expected.  Any ideas?

Details:
The Access module with the inconsistency opens Word 2007 and creates a new document from a template (.dotx) file using bookmarks to merge Access data into the document.  This works as designed without a problem and works every time.  Once the document is created, the vba code calls the Word window to front.  This does not happen unless I select View Code and Save. I do not have to modify any code, just select Save. Then it works as expected until I close the database.  When I next open the database and select the button that creates the Word document, the document is not brought to front but remains behind the Access window.  If I select View Code and Save, the subsequent documents created during that session come to front as desired.  This is consistent and repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about why this is occurring, but a quick fix that I thought might work would be to programmatically save the module when you load your DB.

```
docmd.save acmodule, "module name"
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Liam:  Thanks.  Your code did not work but it gave me a lead on how to fix the problem.  The VBA code is in a Class Module and kept telling me that the object was not open. After some trial and error, I found that this fixes the problem:  

Private Sub Form_Load()  
     DoCmd.OpenModule "Form_frmOrderEntry"
     DoCmd.Save
     DoCmd.Close acModule, "Form_frmOrderEntry"
End Sub

The Code Editor window flashes when this code runs.  Do you know of any way to have this run in the background?

Comment: There's a `ScreenUpdate` that you can set to `false` at the start of the code then `true` at the end... You may have to google the exact syntax but it's pretty straight forward. I'm not sure why the vba editor becomes visible, I've never seen that before. However the `ScreenUpdate` should fix it

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  I also found that setting the Application.VBA.MainWindow.Height = 0 before the code and Application.VBA.MainWindow.Height = 840 after the code causes the "flash" to be nearly unnoticeable.